# Is it possible to make a comparison with the one views?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-views

I integrated a view into a template with Twig Tweak.

I would like to use the comparison feature, to display a font-awesome only if the view contains the class `.alert` for example.

Or if the view contains the word "Taches".

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#comparisons

region--navigation.html.twig

```
{% if '.alert' in drupal_view_result('accueil_page_liste_des_taches_utilisateur', 'block_1') %}
  <i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-lg position-absolute"></i>
{% endif %}
```

This view only displays the rendered entity of the user's display mode. Here is the display mode rewritten in a template :

```
{{ {'#cache': {'max-age': 0}} }}

{% set dangers = 0 %}
{% if drupal_view_result('utilisateur_page_liste_des_taches_aucune_invitation', 'block_1', user.id()) is empty %}
  {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if drupal_view_result('utilisateur_page_liste_des_taches_aucune_photo', 'block_1', user.id()) is empty %}
  {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if drupal_view_result('utilisateur_page_liste_des_taches_aucun_groupe', 'block_1', user.id()) is empty %}
  {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if drupal_view_result('utilisateur_page_liste_des_taches_mode_de_paiement', 'block_1', user.id()) is empty %}
  {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
{% endif %}

{% if dangers or warnings > 0 %}
  <div class="alert alert-light border overflow-hidden shadow rounded hover mt-5 mb-0" role="alert">
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-tasks fa-2x mr-4 float-left"></i>
      <div class="alert-heading h5 mt-0 mb-2">Des tâches requièrent votre attention dans votre compte utilisateur.</div>
      <small>Veuillez passer en revue <a href="/user/{{ user.id }}/tasks" data-drupal-link-system-path="/user/{{ user.id }}/tasks">cette liste</a>.</small>
    </div>
    <hr class="mt-3 mb-3 border">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
      {% if dangers > 0 %}
        <p class="text-center mb-0"><i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x text-danger"></i><br>{{ dangers }} importante{% if dangers > 1 %}s{% endif %}</p>
      {% endif %}
      {% if warnings > 0 %}
        <p class="text-center mb-0"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x text-warning"></i><br>{{ warnings }} avertissement{% if warnings > 1 %}s{% endif %}</p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

The view should not display anything, but simply check if the class or word is present and display the font-awesome.

Comment: You are mixing concepts here. Twig knows nothing about css, in a `<div class="alert">`, twig cannot find `.alert` because it is nowhere to be found. You could find `alert` but that would obviously yield false positives. What you want to achieve might be possible in pure css, where you can say that an element would display or not based on subsequently displayed element's classes. This said, your recent questions in here tends to make me believe that you are trying to get in twig some logic that you should put in a controller, a session or something way better than using a rendered view...

Comment: Maybe looking a bit at the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) could give you a better look at why I am saying that fitting those in a view is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thank you for your explanations, but to create a controller, you have to know how to program. My views are complex and refer to several types of entity (user, group, drupal commerce). Here is what I want to do: if there is a "warning" or a "danger", a font-awesome should appear on the logo of the site to notify the user.

Comment: By doing such complex things in your view you know quite a bit already... you are possibly doing in twig here things more complex than one newbie would in a controller. Symfony (underlaying Drupal framework) is not that hard to start with, on controllers. I don't have much experience with the new versions of Drupal, since it is a Symfony app, so I don't know exactly the overhead here, but you might want to give it a shot.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I just created a custom module start for Drupal 8.9 https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3076032/-/tree/master I don't know how to count tasks or create tasks.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3076032/-/tree/master I'm looking to do the 3 paths for 3 different entities `/user/USER_ID/tasks`, `/store/STORE_ID/tasks` and `/group/GROUP_ID/tasks`